# 'Work hard at it' or 'work hard for it'. Which is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> Some people dream of success, while others wake up and work hard at it.

My friend and I got into a little argument over which is correct. He says 'work hard at it' is correct. I disagreed and said it should be 'work hard for it'.

I'd be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this.

Comment: Both *at* and *for* are **grammatically** correct. They are even semantically very similar.

Comment: Is it a job or a goal?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure **work hard for it** is correct in this situation. 'it' is referring to success. 'work hard at it' would be used if 'it' referred to something that you can do and since you can not do success that doesn't really work. 'work hard for it' would be used if 'it' referred to an potential outcome or goal of your work. Success can definitely be an outcome of working hard so that is the wording I would go with.

Answer (score 1):

**work hard at it** implies simply putting a lot of effort into a job.

**work hard for it** implies applying great effort in the pursuit of a goal.

Answer (score 0):

Both are similar. In some contexts, one will imply that the objective was reached or is about to be reached, with more emphasis than the other.